# How to check a column of a csv file and add data from another column to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I apologize if the question wasn't very clear. I am VERY new to reading/analyzing csv files, and I was tasked with creating a list by checking the last column and adding its value from another column.

I need to gather the values from column 2 and add them to a list based on the column 4 values.

Column 4 has three different "Species" (iris-setosa, iris-virginica, iris-versicolor), and each are associated with 50 values from column 2. I only need to focus on iris-setosa and iris-virginica.

The file is already sorted, so I was able to somewhat print what I expected, but I am having a difficult time finding the correct way to do it so that I can correlate the data later.

This is what I have so far...

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
def makeDataList(dataName):
    inFile = open("Iris.csv", 'r')
    dataList = []

    csvReader = csv.reader(inFile)    
    titles = next(csvReader)      

    colNum = 0
    while colNum < len(titles) and titles[colNum] != dataName:
        colNum = colNum + 1

    if colNum == len(titles):        
        print("Error:", dataName, "not found.")
    else:
        dataList = [float(line[colNum]) for line in csvReader]
            
    return dataList


setosaList = makeDataList("PetalLengthCm")
print("setosa petal length: ")
for i in range(50):
    print(setosaList[i],end=" ")

print()

virginicaList = makeDataList("PetalLengthCm")
print("Virginica petal length: ")
for i in range(100,150):
    print(virginicaList[i],end=" ")
```

Output:

```
setosa petal length: 
1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.6 1.4 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.3 1.4 1.7 1.5 1.7 1.5 1.0 1.7 1.9 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.2 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.6 1.9 1.4 1.6 1.4 1.5 1.4 
Virginica petal length: 
6.0 5.1 5.9 5.6 5.8 6.6 4.5 6.3 5.8 6.1 5.1 5.3 5.5 5.0 5.1 5.3 5.5 6.7 6.9 5.0 5.7 4.9 6.7 4.9 5.7 6.0 4.8 4.9 5.6 5.8 6.1 6.4 5.6 5.1 5.6 6.1 5.6 5.5 4.8 5.4 5.6 5.1 5.1 5.9 5.7 5.2 5.0 5.2 5.4 5.1
```

Expected Output:

```
setosa petal length: [1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7,...]
Virginica petal length: [6.0, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.6,...]
```

The file in plaintext:

```
SepalLengthCm SepalWidthCm PetalLengthCm PetalWidthCm Species         
5.1           3.5          1.4           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.9           3.0          1.4           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.7           3.2          1.3           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.6           3.1          1.5           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5             3.6          1.4           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.4           3.9          1.7           0.4          Iris-setosa     
4.6           3.4          1.4           0.3          Iris-setosa     
5             3.4          1.5           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.4           2.9          1.4           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.9           3.1          1.5           0.1          Iris-setosa     
5.4           3.7          1.5           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.8           3.4          1.6           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.8           3            1.4           0.1          Iris-setosa     
4.3           3            1.1           0.1          Iris-setosa     
5.8           4            1.2           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.7           4.4          1.5           0.4          Iris-setosa     
5.4           3.9          1.3           0.4          Iris-setosa     
5.1           3.5          1.4           0.3          Iris-setosa     
5.7           3.8          1.7           0.3          Iris-setosa     
5.1           3.8          1.5           0.3          Iris-setosa     
5.4           3.4          1.7           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.1           3.7          1.5           0.4          Iris-setosa     
4.6           3.6          1             0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.1           3.3          1.7           0.5          Iris-setosa     
4.8           3.4          1.9           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5             3            1.6           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5             3.4          1.6           0.4          Iris-setosa     
5.2           3.5          1.5           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.2           3.4          1.4           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.7           3.2          1.6           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.8           3.1          1.6           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.4           3.4          1.5           0.4          Iris-setosa     
5.2           4.1          1.5           0.1          Iris-setosa     
5.5           4.2          1.4           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.9           3.1          1.5           0.1          Iris-setosa     
5             3.2          1.2           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.5           3.5          1.3           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.9           3.1          1.5           0.1          Iris-setosa     
4.4           3            1.3           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.1           3.4          1.5           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5             3.5          1.3           0.3          Iris-setosa     
4.5           2.3          1.3           0.3          Iris-setosa     
4.4           3.2          1.3           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5             3.5          1.6           0.6          Iris-setosa     
5.1           3.8          1.9           0.4          Iris-setosa     
4.8           3            1.4           0.3          Iris-setosa     
5.1           3.8          1.6           0.2          Iris-setosa     
4.6           3.2          1.4           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5.3           3.7          1.5           0.2          Iris-setosa     
5             3.3          1.4           0.2          Iris-setosa     
7             3.2          4.7           1.4          Iris-versicolor 
6.4           3.2          4.5           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
6.9           3.1          4.9           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
5.5           2.3          4             1.3          Iris-versicolor 
6.5           2.8          4.6           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
5.7           2.8          4.5           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
6.3           3.3          4.7           1.6          Iris-versicolor 
4.9           2.4          3.3           1            Iris-versicolor 
6.6           2.9          4.6           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
5.2           2.7          3.9           1.4          Iris-versicolor 
5             2            3.5           1            Iris-versicolor 
5.9           3            4.2           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
6             2.2          4             1            Iris-versicolor 
6.1           2.9          4.7           1.4          Iris-versicolor 
5.6           2.9          3.6           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
6.7           3.1          4.4           1.4          Iris-versicolor 
5.6           3            4.5           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
5.8           2.7          4.1           1            Iris-versicolor 
6.2           2.2          4.5           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
5.6           2.5          3.9           1.1          Iris-versicolor 
5.9           3.2          4.8           1.8          Iris-versicolor 
6.1           2.8          4             1.3          Iris-versicolor 
6.3           2.5          4.9           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
6.1           2.8          4.7           1.2          Iris-versicolor 
6.4           2.9          4.3           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
6.6           3            4.4           1.4          Iris-versicolor 
6.8           2.8          4.8           1.4          Iris-versicolor 
6.7           3            5             1.7          Iris-versicolor 
6             2.9          4.5           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
5.7           2.6          3.5           1            Iris-versicolor 
5.5           2.4          3.8           1.1          Iris-versicolor 
5.5           2.4          3.7           1            Iris-versicolor 
5.8           2.7          3.9           1.2          Iris-versicolor 
6             2.7          5.1           1.6          Iris-versicolor 
5.4           3            4.5           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
6             3.4          4.5           1.6          Iris-versicolor 
6.7           3.1          4.7           1.5          Iris-versicolor 
6.3           2.3          4.4           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
5.6           3            4.1           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
5.5           2.5          4             1.3          Iris-versicolor 
5.5           2.6          4.4           1.2          Iris-versicolor 
6.1           3            4.6           1.4          Iris-versicolor 
5.8           2.6          4             1.2          Iris-versicolor 
5             2.3          3.3           1            Iris-versicolor 
5.6           2.7          4.2           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
5.7           3            4.2           1.2          Iris-versicolor 
5.7           2.9          4.2           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
6.2           2.9          4.3           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
5.1           2.5          3             1.1          Iris-versicolor 
5.7           2.8          4.1           1.3          Iris-versicolor 
6.3           3.3          6             2.5          Iris-virginica  
5.8           2.7          5.1           1.9          Iris-virginica  
7.1           3            5.9           2.1          Iris-virginica  
6.3           2.9          5.6           1.8          Iris-virginica  
6.5           3            5.8           2.2          Iris-virginica  
7.6           3            6.6           2.1          Iris-virginica  
4.9           2.5          4.5           1.7          Iris-virginica  
7.3           2.9          6.3           1.8          Iris-virginica  
6.7           2.5          5.8           1.8          Iris-virginica  
7.2           3.6          6.1           2.5          Iris-virginica  
6.5           3.2          5.1           2            Iris-virginica  
6.4           2.7          5.3           1.9          Iris-virginica  
6.8           3            5.5           2.1          Iris-virginica  
5.7           2.5          5             2            Iris-virginica  
5.8           2.8          5.1           2.4          Iris-virginica  
6.4           3.2          5.3           2.3          Iris-virginica  
6.5           3            5.5           1.8          Iris-virginica  
7.7           3.8          6.7           2.2          Iris-virginica  
7.7           2.6          6.9           2.3          Iris-virginica  
6             2.2          5             1.5          Iris-virginica  
6.9           3.2          5.7           2.3          Iris-virginica  
5.6           2.8          4.9           2            Iris-virginica  
7.7           2.8          6.7           2            Iris-virginica  
6.3           2.7          4.9           1.8          Iris-virginica  
6.7           3.3          5.7           2.1          Iris-virginica  
7.2           3.2          6             1.8          Iris-virginica  
6.2           2.8          4.8           1.8          Iris-virginica  
6.1           3            4.9           1.8          Iris-virginica  
6.4           2.8          5.6           2.1          Iris-virginica  
7.2           3            5.8           1.6          Iris-virginica  
7.4           2.8          6.1           1.9          Iris-virginica  
7.9           3.8          6.4           2            Iris-virginica  
6.4           2.8          5.6           2.2          Iris-virginica  
6.3           2.8          5.1           1.5          Iris-virginica  
6.1           2.6          5.6           1.4          Iris-virginica  
7.7           3            6.1           2.3          Iris-virginica  
6.3           3.4          5.6           2.4          Iris-virginica  
6.4           3.1          5.5           1.8          Iris-virginica  
6             3            4.8           1.8          Iris-virginica  
6.9           3.1          5.4           2.1          Iris-virginica  
6.7           3.1          5.6           2.4          Iris-virginica  
6.9           3.1          5.1           2.3          Iris-virginica  
5.8           2.7          5.1           1.9          Iris-virginica  
6.8           3.2          5.9           2.3          Iris-virginica  
6.7           3.3          5.7           2.5          Iris-virginica  
6.7           3            5.2           2.3          Iris-virginica  
6.3           2.5          5             1.9          Iris-virginica  
6.5           3            5.2           2            Iris-virginica  
6.2           3.4          5.4           2.3          Iris-virginica  
5.9           3            5.1           1.8          Iris-virginica
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the image of a portion of the contents of the csv file with that actual _contents_ of that portion in plain text.

Comment: Hello! I tried to copy it in plain text, and added the whole thing.

Comment: Is that what the data really looks like or are there commas (or possibly tab-characters) between the columns in each row? It's also unclear exactly you're asking — what your question is. What do you mean by "the correct way to do it so that I can correlate the data later"? What's wrong with the way you're doing it now?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the package pandas (`pip install pandas`). This has a lot of functionality for dealing with data, including reading data from a csv file.
To read in the data, you can use

```
import pandas as  pd
iris_data = pd.read_csv("Iris.csv")
```

Then you can access each column using `iris_data["column_name"]`. To get all the sepal lengths where the species is  iris-setosa or iris-virginica, you can use

```
setosa_petal_length = iris_data["PetalLengthCm"][iris_data["species"]=="Iris-setosa"]
virginica_petal_length = iris_data["PetalLengthCm"][iris_data["species"]=="Iris-virginica"]
```

There are a load of introductory tutorials for pandas out there, but [this one](https://github.com/jvns/pandas-cookbook) is linked to from the pandas website, or you can click on "getting started" [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas here. **But I noticed, that your spacings in the data is off**. First spacing is 11 spaces, followed by 10. That messes up some things. A classic csv would just have a comma separating each value or name. Than pandas would directly read it in correctly.

then you can try to import the file and then set your fields by hand:

```
import pandas as pd
fields=['SepalLengthCm','SepalWidthCm','PetalLengthCm','PetalWidthCm','Species']

df=pd.read_csv('./test.csv', header=None, names=fields,sep='          ') #  Here the separators are not the same
```

Later you can play around with the dataframe and e.g. get all values of one column.

```
newdf = df.set_index('Locality').T #Transpose the dataframe to make your species callable

df.loc['Iris-setosa'].values.totlist() # GEt the values of all the string you are looking for.
```

As the separators were off, I could not full test this. I guess you still have to adjust it. But red into pandas, you can do anything you want to do.